# How to remove a specific line on a text file base on 2 user inputs with Python?

Tags: python, file, input, truncate, seek

So far this is what I have. I'm trying to make it so that the program asks for the user to input the author of a book and the ISBN of a book, then if there is a line in the file that contains both of these variables, it will remove that line completely.

```
print()
            print("Removing a Book")
            print()
            removebookAuthor=(input("Provide the author of the book you would like to remove>"))
            removebookISBN=(input("Provide the ISBN of the book you would like to remove>"))
            with open("books.txt","r+") as f:
                new_f = f.readlines()
                f.seek(2)
                for line in new_f:
                    if "removebookAuthor"+"removebookISBN" in line:
                        f.write(line)
                f.truncate()
```

For reference, the text document looks something like this:

```
Python Crash Course - 2nd Edition;Matthes,Eric;978-1593279288;005.133/MAT;12;8;
Python for Dummies;Maruch,Stef;978-0471778646;005.133/MAR;5;0;
Beginning Programming with Python for Dummies;Mueller,John Paul;978-1119457893;005.133/MUE;7;5;
Beginning COBOL for Programmers;Coughlan,Michael;978-1430262534;005.133/COU;1;0;
```

Example of removebookAuthor would be "**Maruch,Stef**"
Example of removebookISBN would be "**978-0471778646**"

So far, the program completely clears the entire document. Not too sure how to go about fixing this. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `f.truncate()` line ?

Comment: Removing the f.truncate() line does nothing new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if condition is not written correctly. You could use `not in` for your both conditions:

```py
removebookAuthor = input("Provide the author of the book you would like to remove>")
removebookISBN = input("Provide the ISBN of the book you would like to remove>")

with open("books.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(2)
    for line in lines:
        if removebookAuthor not in line and removebookISBN not in line:
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```